# Check equality from a void pointer typecasted data

Tags: c++

in my below program i get compilation error

```
error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'unsigned char*' and 'const char*' lacks a cast
```

How to tackle this and do comparison

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec;

void Init(void* tmp)
{
    auto dd = static_cast<std::uint8_t *>(tmp);
    std::cout<<"loop : "<<dd<<std::endl;
    if(dd == "BBBB_DDDDD_XXUSTYY_99_7DFFXX9B67")
      std::cout<<"equal";
    else
      std::cout<<"not equal";
}

std::string PadIt(std::string& str, std::size_t outputLength)
{
    if (outputLength > str.size()) {
        char paddingChar = ' ';
        str.insert(str.size(), outputLength - str.size(), paddingChar);
    }
    std::cout<<"PadIt str is : "<<str<<" size is: "<<str.size()<<std::endl;
    return str;
}  

int main() {

    std::string key_str = "BBBB_DDDDD_XXUSTYY_99_7DFFXX9B67";
    std::string obid = PadIt(key_str,16);
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec(obid.begin(),obid.end());
    Init(vec.data());

  
}
```

I want to do comparison of string in Init function, if a wrong string is given it show give false

Comment: What exactly are you intending to do with the comparison `if(dd == "BBBB_DDDDD_XXUSTYY_99_7DFFXX9B67")`?

Comment: Why do you cast to `std::uint8_t *` when you intend to compare to a `char*`?

Comment: That comparison will *never* be `true`, unless you pass in a pointer to the exact same literal string.

Comment: This needs elaboration of what is the *problem* this is supposed to solve, because frankly it has a design aroma that isn't exactly pleasant. You should update your post to include what this is intended to do, and *why*.

Comment: The comparison is pointless - the location of the first element of a `std::vector` can't be the same as the location of the first element of an array (or any other object).

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks i tried giving auto dd = static_cast<char *>(tmp); then there is no compilation error, but it false to not equal to why is that. How can i accomplish a succeful comparison here

Comment: Just a warning: even `"aaa" == "aaa"` might return false. `"aaa" == <pointer to dynamically allocated memory>` is __guaranteed__ to return false.

Comment: If you want to compare strings, why are my messing about with `std::vector` and `void*`? I think one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would be good for you. Read in particular about arrays, pointers, array-to-pointer decay, and the differences between "C-style" strings and `std::string`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Init` function by the way. It doesn't seem to actually be doing any kind "init" or initialization. Good naming is very important to make code easier to read, understand, debug and generally maintain.

Comment: Also, [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) are bad, the same goes for magic strings.

Comment: @molbdnilo my actual project case need these datatype conversions

Comment: And be careful: The data you store in the vector is *not* a null-terminated string. Any attempt to use that data as a null-terminated string will fail.

Comment: I figured out it works like this     std::string data = "BBBB_DDDDD_XXUSTYY_99_7DFFXX9B67";
    std::string dd = static_cast<char *>(tmp);
    if(dd == data)
        std::cout<<"equal";
    else
        std::cout<<"not equal";

Comment: A working result - https://godbolt.org/z/TWexv6G9z